# DataFrame is empty, expected data in it

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find duplicate items within 2 rows in Excel. So for example my Excel consists of:

```
    list_A  list_B
0   ideal   ideal
1   brown   colour
2   blue    blew
3   red     red
```

I checked the pandas documentation and tried duplicate method but I simply don't know why it keeps saying "DataFrame is empty". It finds both columns and I guess it's iterated over it but why doesn't it find the values and compare them?

I also tried using iterrows but honestly don't know how to implement it.

When running the code I get this output:

Empty DataFrame

Columns: [list A, list B]

Index: []

```
import pandas as pd

pt = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\S531\Desktop\pt.xlsx")
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(pt)
doubles = dfObj[dfObj.duplicated()]      
print(doubles)
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
    list_A  list_B
0   ideal   ideal
3   red     red
```

Final solved code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

pt = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\S531\Desktop\pt.xlsx")
doubles = pt[pt['list_A'] == pt['list_B']]
print(doubles)
```

Comment: `pt` should already be a `DataFrame` object, so no reason for `dfObj = pd.DataFrame(pt)` ... what do you get when you print `pt`?

Comment: when I add print(pt) I get: list A  list B
0  ideal   ideal
1  brown  colour
2   blue    blew
3    red     red

Comment: Okay, now we know your example input is read properly. I've suggested an edit, so it's easy to see the dataframe and copy it. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "duplicate" is usually used to mean rows that are exact duplicates of previous rows (see the documentation of [pd.DataFrame.duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)).

What you are looking for is just the rows where these two columns are equal. For that, you want:

`doubles = pt[pt['list_A'] == pt['list_B']]`

Comment: thanks your really fast replies. Yes, correct, I haven´t been precise enough. what does the final code look like? do I have to assign it to my "doubles" variable? and finally just print(doubles). I tried it but got a bunch of traceback messages...

Comment: yes, that would work. try `doubles = pt[pt['list_A'] == pt['list_B']]` and printing `doubles`.

Comment: If you're getting a bunch of traceback messages, it might be that I made an error in my answer - what error messages are you getting?

Comment: solved, thank you very much. I got an error message because in your edit you added an underscore to list_A. I didn´t see this detail immediately. And I changed "df" to "pt" since my variable is called pt

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited from `df` to `pt` for clarity. If this answer answers your question, please mark it as accepted (with the little "v" sign), so that others will know it is answered.